# What is non-css presentational hints?

Tags: css, fonts, presentation

When reading css related text, I've came across this rather cryptic sentence:
"It is possible that a document will contain presentational hints that are not CSS - for example, the font element.".

I am not quite sure what "non-css presentational hints" are and what are their use cases.

Are they legacy features which are depreciated now? Could someone give an example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In HTML*, they are rendering guidance drawn from features that are frequently but not always obsolete.

In general, if a feature's *only* purpose is presentational - like the `<font>` element - then it will be obsolete. Nevertheless, it will still normally have an effect on the rendering in browsers. For example, the `<center>` element centres its contents horizontally on the page, but because it is obsolete, is should not be used. The CSS declaration `text-align:center` should be used instead.

However, features can have uses beyond the rendering, for example, the height and width attributes of `<img>` element are intended to convey information about the intrisic size of the image, without having to download that image. That means that a browser can use that information to decide whether to download the image, using up what might be precious bandwidth, or not. *In addition*, the information can be used as a presentational hint to determine the space used on screen to display the image, when there is no CSS doing that available. These attributes are not obsolete.

For more information see the HTML5 spec [14.2 The CSS user agent style sheet and presentational hints](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#the-css-user-agent-style-sheet-and-presentational-hints).